# Congratulations, Qiaochu!

Tags: discussion, specific-user

The 100k club (or "100k-club", if you care about hyphens) has increased in size again!

Comment: Hear, hear! Nice work, @Qiaochu!

Comment: I find admirable for a 22-year man to have such math knowledge. I'm 24 and although working hard, I still dream about it...

Comment: Congratulations, Qiaochu!

Comment: @Jeyekomon: you will get there.

Comment: Congrats!${}{}$

Comment: If stackexchange had been invented when I was your age I might never have become a vicar ... stunningly good performance. This forum makes maths visibly international, and raises the bar for everyone. Blindingly good performance. Congratulations Qiaochu! 200k beckons ...?

Comment: Congratulations, Qiaochu!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Thanks, everyone! I'm happy that people are getting something out of my contributions.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, indeed! Qiaochu, thanks for your contribution to MSE!

Comment: Not only a prolific answerer, but a prodigious moderator!  Please add my thanks, Qiaochu Yuan!

Comment: @hardmath: It is impossible to read the word "prodigious" without thinking back to Dr. Strangelove.

Answer (score 23):

Qiaochu's questions are valuable too. I respect his willingness to admit to the world he doesn't know *everything*. Not everyone is secure enough in their own knowledge and abilities to do that. Count me as a fan. (Forgive me: in my head I read your name as Pikachu.)

Answer (score 6):

Qiaochu's research is really appreciable. The fact that he is only in his 20's and is liable to become a Mathematics professor is unbelievable. I wonder *how* he did all this in such a short time! I really love his [blog](http://qchu.wordpress.com/).

Best of luck for the future! **We guys are with you!**

P.S.: 200k is not too far! [image]